# What is water's center of mass?

Tags: water, fluid-statics, volume

Suppose there is a cube filled with water of height $h$. Where would the center of mass be? I would assume that since water is denser where it is deeper, the center of mass should move toward the bottom as the $h$ increases.

Comment: Water is almost non-compressible. At normal size scales, there is no measurable difference in density with its depth.

Answer (score 2):

Water doesn’t change density significantly. Even at the bottom of the ocean, effects due to temperature and salinity are much larger than those for pressure.

The c.m. will be in the center of the uniform mass: h/2. So it will *rise* as you add water and increase h.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, water is very well approximated as an incompressible fluid. To answer your question, however, suppose you had some material which had a density which varies spatially, so $\rho = \rho(\mathbf{x})$. Then the center of mass $\mathbf{R}$ is readily obtained by
$$\mathbf{R}=\frac{1}{M} \int \mathbf{r} \rho(\mathbf{r})  d^3 x.$$
For the sake of argument, consider some 2-dimensional arrangement of $\rho$. We suppose that $\rho$ is constant horizontally along $x$ and varies linearly with depth, so $\rho(x,y) = \rho_0 y.$ Then the center of mass's location in $y$ is given by:
$$Y = \frac{w}{M} \int_0^{h} \rho_0 y^2 dy = \frac{w\rho_0 h^3}{3M} \sim h^3$$
where $w$ is the width of the container. So as the depth increases linearly, the center of mass's location sinks cubically, which makes sense since the majority of the mass is building up lower in the container.

Comment: I think that calculation has the denser water at the top

Comment: It should be clarified that the $h=0$ point is defined to be at the top of the container, and that $\hat{\mathbf{y}}$ is pointing downward. Perhaps that clears the conclusion that the denser water is bottom.